# Enabling hermes for react-native 0.68. Worth it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an app I have been working on for a long time, currently it uses React Native 0.68.2 version, everything builds correctly!

I just read about the [Hermes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) JavaScript engine that seems to run a little more smooth. I'm thinking if it's worth it to enable Hermes for my app? Will it break on compile?

Currently I don't want to upgrade React Native to a newer version in fear something will break.

Is enabling Hermes as easy as adding the following to my *[gradle.properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)* file?

```
hermesEnabled=true
```

Comment: Yes, it's worth to enable Hermes, the speed is improved (significantly if your code base is large, otherwise it's hard to realize), the bundle size is less (again not too much). But there will be some issues if you are not lucky enough :). I can't remember all of those, however if you don't enable Fabric, then most of the issues can be solved by upgrading libraries to latest.